# insert php variable at the end of url string with an iFrame

Tags: iframe

Here is what i've done so far but i just keep getting an error

```
<?php echo (($flag_show_product_info_model == 1 and $products_model !='') ? '<li>' . TEXT_PRODUCT_MODEL . $products_model . '</li>' : '') . "\n"; ?>


<iframe src="http://www.madisonb2b.co.uk/stockenquiry.aspx?id=B8FxKDnJ%2bIdaPT1Nw5wo4r87qHuHcCQIPZzeUE%2fI36LIFOM%2bayBi2RSXHzIJS5Hj97JNSyYL80Q%3d&code=<?php {$product_model} ?>"</iframe>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<iframe src="http://www.madisonb2b.co.uk/stockenquiry.aspx?id=B8FxKDnJ%2bIdaPT1Nw5wo4r87qHuHcCQIPZzeUE%2fI36LIFOM%2bayBi2RSXHzIJS5Hj97JNSyYL80Q%3d&code=<?php echo $product_model ?>"</iframe>
```

(will work if $product_model is defined by the time you echo it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to say

```
echo $product_model
```

instead of

```
{$product_model}
```

?