# Search box sends input to a iframe url on a new page

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I want to have a search box where a person types in a number and the form opens a new page where there is an iframe and the url of the iframe is http://othersite.com/results.php?id=numbersinputfromsearchbox

Is this possible? I am using wordpress with php/mysql/apache/linux if that helps you to answer me. Thanks!!

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141189/insert-php-variable-at-the-end-of-url-string-with-an-iframe

Sorry I am very new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://othersite.com/results.php?id=numbersblahblah" method="post" target="_blank">
    <!-- form fields here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: The iframe will be on a different page on my own site.

Comment: As far as I know you can post to an iframe on the same page, but not on another page. To hack around it you can serialize the form on post, using `$(this).serialize();", append that to the `action` of the form, then unserialize it at the other end and create an iframe element, then append it to the body... but it really is very, very messy. Are you sure there's no alternative, cleaner solution? :)